# VB.NET's literal -32768S is an overflow

Tags: vb.net

In VB.NET, you can declare a literal datatype by added various characters at the end of a value, such as 100L for Int64, 100UL for UInt64, 100S for Int16, etc...

This can be used to implicitly set a variable (similar to C# var):

```
Dim s = -32767S 'this is now implicitly an Int16
```

However, for Int16, if I want the minimum value of -32768, this flags as an overflow error:

```
Dim s = -32768S '<-- this will be flagged as an overflow error
```

Yet, I can do this:

```
Dim s = Int16.MinValue '<-- this is also -32768S, just without the overflow error
```

I can always use an Int32 and it will automatically convert if I declare the variable as an Int16:

```
Dim s As Int16 = -32768 '<-- no overflow because -32768 is an Int32
```

I tried googling for a reason that -32768S was excluded from the literal set, but could not find an answer. Just curious if anyone knows of a reason/backstory as to how this happened.

Comment: It doesn't work because a literal can't be negative (an integer literal consists only of digits 0-9 and an optional suffix), the `-` is a regular unary minus and _not_ part of the literal. So it's taking the positive literal and then the unary minus operation is applied, essentially `-(32768S)`. And `32768S` is out of range since it's above the maximum value of 32767, hence the error.

Comment: @CherryDT Now I get it, it's not that an Int16 can't be a negative value, it's that a LITERAL cannot be declared as a negative value. Got it...... nice!